# NodeJS not compatible

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, spfx-extensions

when I run gulp serve I get the following error.

**`Your dev environment is running NodeJS version v10.15.0 which does not meet the requirements for running this tool. This tool requires a version of NodeJS that matches >=8.9.4 <9.0.0`**

My current version of

```
 - Node is 10.15
 - Gulp is 3.9
 - @Microsoft/sp-core-library -1.7.1
```

I followed this [article](https://n8d.at/blog/how-to-use-specific-nodejs-version-with-your-spfx-project/) but it works only for Microsoft framework 1.2.0 but it does not work for Microsoft framework 1.6.0  or Microsoft 1.7.1

When I follow the above article I can run `gulp serve` but I cannot include the

```
import { AadHttpClient, HttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

as it is only supported in spfx framework 1.6 and above.

Is there a way to get the workbench working.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint Framework do you use?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The SharePoint framework is 1.7.1

Comment: are you using the following command to serve `npx -p node@8 gulp serve` ? (notice the number 8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `nvm` (node version manager) to quickly switch between different nodejs versions. [Download for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) or [OSX version](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

### How to use

1. Install nvm
2. `$ nvm install 8.11.0` - installs nodejs version 8.11.0
3. `$ nvm use 8.11.0` - now your system uses 8.11 version of nodejs. With that version you can run `gulp serve` without issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. You are a life saver. Should we avoid node v10.15 completely for now.

Comment: Well, for SharePoint Framework projects yes, you should avoid, but for everything else, it's totally fine. Actually I've created a tool, which fixes SPFx project and allows you to use nodejs 10.x - [the link](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/spfx-fix-node10). It's not official, but I use it and it works good.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following:

1. Install nvm (https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)
2. Then install the 64-Bit version for windows:

```
nvm install 8.9.4 64
```

3. Then type the following to use the earlier version:

```
nvm use 8.9.4 64
```

4. Then run your project as before, for example:

```
gulp serve
```

Here is more info: https://o365insights.com/downgrade-npm-for-spfx-1.7.0/

In some rare cases, doing the above still doesn't work, so it is best to find the  offending .msi file in your downloads folder, for example **node-v10.15.1-x64.msi**, then do a right-click on it and Uninstall it. You then have to install an earlier version, such as v8.9.4. The different versions can be found here:

https://nodejs.org/download/release/

Version 8.9.4 is found here: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.9.4/
(for windows and other OS)

In my case, once v8.9.4 was installed, I did a **gulp serve** and everything started working again. Close Visual Studio Code and restart it first!

Answer (score 0):

on windows, if not working, then delete or rename C:\Program Files\nodejs as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017812/nvm-use-does-not-switch-node-versions