# gulp serve error

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, error, spfx-tooling

I'm trying to work on a project of a SPFx web part. The project was built normally but when I try to test my web part on my tenant the following error occurs:

> Error: Your dev environment is running NodeJS version v18.12.1 which does not meet the requirements for running this tool. This tool requires a version of NodeJS that matches >=12.13.0 <13.0.0 || >=14.15.0 <15.0.0 || >=16.13.0 <17.0.0

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of SPFx generator are you using?

Comment: I am using sharepoint@1.16.1. So how am I supposed to degrade node js. Do I have to uninstall the latest one?

Comment: Yes, uninstall the node js and again instal node js v16.13+. check my answer below for compatible version & more information

Comment: After installing node js v16.13.0, I am facing another error: [18:45:58] Error - 'spfx-serve' sub task errored after 332 ms .   No development certificate found. Generate a new certificate manually or set the `canGenerateNewCertificate` parameter to `true` when calling `ensureCertificateAsync`.     Was I suppose to run something after installing the new one?

Comment: Run this command: `gulp trust-dev-cert`. Follow this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Comment: Please check the NodeJS version and spfx version in the document 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility#spfx-development-environment-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You are using Node JS version v18.12.1 which is not supported for SPFx development.

You have to use the supported Node JS version based on the SPFx version you are using.

For example:

[image]

Check this compatibility matrix for complete list: [SPFx development environment compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility#spfx-development-environment-compatibility)

---

Also, you can use `nvm` to manage multiple node versions on same development environment, check this for more information: [NodeJS not compatible](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255951/nodejs-not-compatible)